# Does $\sqrt[n]{1+a^n}$ converge to $1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Does the sequence $\sqrt[n]{1+a^n}$, where $0<a<1$, converge to $1$?

This seems correct because $1+a^n\to1$ and $\sqrt[n]1=1$, but that doesn't seem rigorous. It's almost like $\lim f(x_n)=f(\lim x_n)$, but here the function $f$ is changing every time. I've tried factoring the radicand but that just gets me $\sqrt[n]{1+1/a^n}$, which I don't know how to appraoch either.

EDIT: I think I've got it by explicitly writing the $n$-th root as $1+\epsilon_n$ and examining the behavior of $\epsilon_n$ using the binomial theorem, but that seems very ad hoc and I'd prefer a quick solution using a general result.

Comment: You have $a^n→0$ and $a^{1/n}→1$, not the other way round.

Comment: The general proof that I know of that $\sqrt[n]{n}$ relies on the binomial theorem. I'm unsure if there is any other rigorous proof of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $a\in (0,1)$, $a^n\in (0,1)$ and $1\le \sqrt[n]{1+a^n}\le \sqrt[n]{2}$, the result follows.

Answer (score 4):

Use $1 \leq \sqrt[n]{1 + a^n} \leq \sqrt[n]{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$y=\sqrt[n]{1+a^n}$$
Then $$lny=\frac{ln(1+a^n)}{n}$$
Since $ln$ function is continuous, taking limit gives
$$lim_{n\to\infty}y=e^0=1$$